# Dictionary for NLP

Tags: c#, nlp

I am in need of an offline C# (or ANY language for that matter, I can port it over) library that will be able to take a part of speech (that I will detect) and tell me the plural form of the word or the different tenses of the word that I can then turn around and use.

Does such a library exist for the English language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late to jump in, but .NET 4.0 includes a pluralization service

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd486930(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The tool you are looking for is a "morphological generator". It takes a base word and an inflection code, and produces an inflected word form.

However, for English, a plural inflector is just a few lines of code, plus a dictionary of exceptions (base form and inflection for words with an irregular plural form). Just remember to handle the case of words ending on a sibilant.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with other NLP-related tasks in future, I hope, [sharpnlp](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/) will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested with just some rules and a list like what @tripleee mentioned, then you can try/port from MorphAdorner's code. Demo: [MorphAdorner Pluralizer](http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/morphadorner/pluralizer/example/)

But if you are interested with an exhaustive listing you can check [Lexical Tools' Inflection Variants](http://lexsrv3.nlm.nih.gov/LexSysGroup/Projects/lvg/2012/docs/designDoc/UDF/flow/fi.html). After downloading [Lexical Tools](http://lexsrv3.nlm.nih.gov/LexSysGroup/Projects/lvg/2012/web/download.html), you will be importing the data to your database server. Then you can just query the database using their library (Java).